# Ajax working in IE but not chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

```
function chrpajaxscri( formmeth, phpurl ) {

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

    x.open( formmeth, phpurl, true );

    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return x;

}

function ajaxReturn(x){

    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){

       return true; 
    }
}

function chrpsendemail(x,p,e,id,upd,to){

    var name = document.getElementById(id).value;

    var email = document.getElementById(e).value;

    if (name != ""){

        document.getElementById(upd).innerHTML = "Please wait sending ...";

        var ajax = chrpajaxscri("POST", x);

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){

           if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

                document.getElementById(upd).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

        }

    }

    ajax.send("product="+p+"&email="+email+"&name="+name+"&to="+to);

    }
}
```

above is the code i am using to send a request to another file however this works in all browsers apart from google chrome. from what i can tell its a bug with chrome but i still need a fix can any one help please

Comment: Is the status 200? Is there any error messages?

Comment: im not getting any errors :(

Comment: Add debug statements, find out where it is working and not. We can not debug it.